# Is there an algorithm to solve this balancing problem?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I have encountered a balancing problem which I can't figure out how to do for arbitrary numbers of inputs and outputs. The balancing goal is straight forward enough: Balance the input signals evenly on the outputs.

Basic examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucIB3.png

- There are a $n$ inputs and $m$ outputs ($n$ and $m$ are positive integers)
- Inputs signals

  - Unique and does not interfere with other signals, only itself
- Outputs

  - Need an equal amount of each signal ($xi_1 + xi_2 + ... + xi_n$)
  - All outputs must be equal ($o_1 = o_2 = ... =o_m$)
- Cable

  - Signals can only be sent through a cable
  - Inputs and outputs only have one socket

So far we can only handle the problem $n=1, m=1$:

$$i_1 \to O_1(i_1)$$

e.g.

$$o_1 = i_1$$

For all other combinations we need a way to split/balance signals.

- Introducing the Balancer

  - Has two receiver slots and two transmitter slots
  - Works as follows: $r_1 + r_2 = t_1 + t_2$ where $t_1 = t_2$

With this balancer defined, the problem space is established. The goal is to find solutions with as few balancers as possible while also maintaining perfect balance. I will show a few simple problems typed out, and some more with graphs after.

Problem $n=2$, $m=1$ can now be solved with one balancer:

$$i_1, i_2 \to B_1(i_1,i_2) = i_1 + i_2 \to O_1(i_1 + i_2)$$

e.g.

$$o_1 = i_1 + i_2$$

Problem $n=1$, $m=2$ is similar:

$$i_1 \to B_1(i_1) = \frac{2i_1}2 \to O_1(\frac{i_1}2), O_2(\frac{i_1}2)$$

e.g.

$$o_1 = o_2 = \frac{i_1}2$$

Let's skip 2-2 and go straight to the 1-3 problem where it gets quite messy:

$$i_1 \to B_1(i_1,\frac{B_2}2) \to (B_2(\frac{B_1}2) \to B_1, O_1(\frac{B_1}4)), (B_3(\frac{B_1}2) \to O_2(\frac{B_1}4), O_3(\frac{B_1}4))$$

e.g.

$$o_1 = o_2 = o_3 = \frac{B_1}4$$

To see how it relates to the input one can do Gauss-Jordan elimination.

[Shown here, I also show graphs of these and other problems below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02xpZ.jpg). Credits to my new friend [quilan1](https://www.reddit.com/user/quilan1) for teaching me the elimination method and for the graphs. It is much easier to view these problems as graphs, so do check those out. They show optimal solutions for 1 to 3 inputs and 1 to 8 outputs.

This is an interesting problem I encountered in factorio. In the factorio community this is known as the belt balancing problem. I've done my research there already and this is as far as I've come.

I would greatly appreciate any help I could get with this. Please enlighten me! I am not that familiar with (this branch of) maths to be honest. Thank you

Comment: Something I noticed from those examples is that all values that aren't a power of two contain at least one loop. (and singular loops seem to allow factors of mersenne numbers in the denominator of the output based on the size of the loop)